# The most effective way to merge/combine two data sets by overlapping row.names and mean values

Tags: r

I would like to find the most effective way for combining two data frames and average the values in the columns with different row.names . So, I would like to take jsut overlapping row.names from both data and combine them into one. The values from columns should be avaraged by mean. The example datas:

```
mtcars <- 
structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 
24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32.4, 
30.4, 33.9, 21.5, 15.5, 15.2, 13.3, 19.2, 27.3, 26, 30.4, 15.8, 
19.7, 15, 21.4), cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4), 
    disp = c(160, 160, 108, 258, 360, 225, 360, 146.7, 140.8, 
    167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472, 460, 440, 78.7, 75.7, 
    71.1, 120.1, 318, 304, 350, 400, 79, 120.3, 95.1, 351, 145, 
    301, 121), hp = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 
    123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 
    150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175, 335, 109), drat = c(3.9, 
    3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 
    3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 2.93, 3, 3.23, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22, 3.7, 2.76, 
    3.15, 3.73, 3.08, 4.08, 4.43, 3.77, 4.22, 3.62, 3.54, 4.11
    ), wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 
    3.15, 3.44, 3.44, 4.07, 3.73, 3.78, 5.25, 5.424, 5.345, 2.2, 
    1.615, 1.835, 2.465, 3.52, 3.435, 3.84, 3.845, 1.935, 2.14, 
    1.513, 3.17, 2.77, 3.57, 2.78), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 
    19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20, 22.9, 18.3, 18.9, 17.4, 17.6, 
    18, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42, 19.47, 18.52, 19.9, 20.01, 16.87, 
    17.3, 15.41, 17.05, 18.9, 16.7, 16.9, 14.5, 15.5, 14.6, 18.6
    ), vs = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), am = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gear = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4), carb = c(4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 
    2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2)), .Names = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", 
"drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", 
"Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", 
"Valiant", "Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", 
"Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", 
"Lincoln Continental", "Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", 
"Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", 
"Camaro Z28", "Pontiac Firebird", "Fiat X1-9", "Porsche 914-2", 
"Lotus Europa", "Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino", "Maserati Bora", 
"Volvo 142E"), class = "data.frame")
```

Second data:

```
mtcars11 <- 
structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 
24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32.4, 
30.4, 33.9, 21.5, 15.5, 15.2, 13.3, 19.2, 27.3, 26, 30.4, 15.8, 
19.7), cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6), disp = c(160, 160, 
108, 258, 360, 225, 360, 146.7, 140.8, 167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 
275.8, 472, 460, 440, 78.7, 75.7, 71.1, 120.1, 318, 304, 350, 
400, 79, 120.3, 95.1, 351, 145), hp = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 
105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 
52, 65, 97, 150, 150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175), drat = c(3.9, 
3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 3.07, 
3.07, 3.07, 2.93, 3, 3.23, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22, 3.7, 2.76, 3.15, 
3.73, 3.08, 4.08, 4.43, 3.77, 4.22, 3.62), wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 
2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 3.15, 3.44, 3.44, 4.07, 
3.73, 3.78, 5.25, 5.424, 5.345, 2.2, 1.615, 1.835, 2.465, 3.52, 
3.435, 3.84, 3.845, 1.935, 2.14, 1.513, 3.17, 2.77), qsec = c(16.46, 
17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20, 22.9, 18.3, 18.9, 
17.4, 17.6, 18, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42, 19.47, 18.52, 19.9, 20.01, 
16.87, 17.3, 15.41, 17.05, 18.9, 16.7, 16.9, 14.5, 15.5), vs = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), am = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    gear = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5), carb = c(4, 4, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6)), .Names = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", 
"hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", 
"Chrysler", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", 
"Valiant", "Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", 
"Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", "Nexia", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", 
"Lincoln Continental", "Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", 
"Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", 
"Camaro Z28", "Pontiac Firebirda", "Punto", "Porsche 914-2", 
"Lotus Europa", "Ford Pantera T", "Ferrari Dino"), class = "data.frame")
```

So the solution which came to my mind is that (the long one):

```
vec_names_mt <- row.names(mtcars) ## so we the row.names from first data
vec_names_mt11 <- row.names(mtcars11) ## so we the row.names from second data

vec_inter <- intersect(vec_names_mt, vec_names_mt11) ## find overlapping names

data_mt <- mtcars[row.names(mtcars) %in% vec_inter, ] ## take the rows from first data which overlaps
data_mt11 <- mtcars11[row.names(mtcars11) %in% vec_inter, ] ## take the rows from second data which overlaps
```

How can we combine them and average the values ? Any idea how to do that in the simplest way ?

Comment: How will your desired output will look like? Also, there is no need to `dput(mtcars)`- we already have it. Lastly, you probably could reduce this problem to tow much smaller data sets with both less rows *and* columns.

Comment: Also, `data_mt` and `data_mt11` are identical, that's probably not the best example.

Comment: `(mtcars[vec_inter, ] + mtcars11[vec_inter, ])/2`

Comment: The output in that case should look like one of those data. It's just example. I could easly change the values in the columns to have two different data sets but I just wanted to show you what I would like to achieve..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `d1` and `d2` are your data.frames, here's how I'd approach it. You'll have to use [development version of data.table (v1.9.5)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) though, for `mget` to work.

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5

setkey(setDT(d1, keep.rownames=TRUE), rn)
setkey(setDT(d2, keep.rownames=TRUE), rn)

xcols = names(d1)[-1L]
icols = paste("i.", xcols, sep="")

foo <- function(a, b) mean(c(a, b), na.rm=TRUE)
d1[d2, Map(foo, mget(xcols), mget(icols)), by=.EACHI, nomatch=0L]
```

We first convert the *data.frames* to *data.tables* by reference using `setDT`, and convert `row names` to a new column (which will automatically be named `rn`), and set key on that column.

`setkey()` reorders a *data.table* by the columns specified, and marks those columns as *key columns*, which will help us perform a join (on those key columns).

In *data.tables*, joins can be accomplished by using the `x[i]` notation as well as `merge()` function (there's a *data.table* method implemented), but `x[i]` is much more powerful and flexible. The syntax `x[i]` joins each row of `i` to matching rows in `x` (on the key columns).

So, `d1[d2]` would return for each row in `d2` the matching rows in `d1`, along with all the other columns in `d2`.

`d1[d2, nomatch=0L]` is the equivalent of an *inner join*, where only rows that matches are returned.

`d1[d2, Map(foo, mget(xcols), mget(icols)), by=.EACHI, nomatch=0L]` evaluates the expression in `j` = `Map(...)`, for each row in `d2` - hence `by = .EACHI`.

To sum things up, for each row in `d2`, find the matching rows in `d1`. Extract the columns specified in `xcols` and `icols` just for *that* matching rows, and apply the function `foo()` which will concatenate the vectors and take their `mean()`. And do this for each row of `d2` (`by = .EACHI`). Ignore rows in `d2` that doesn't have any matches in `d1` on key column (`nomatch=0L`).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you are looking for an "*inner join*" between two data sets by the row names. I would suggest to try `data.table` package for both merging and the later *melting* and *dcasting* operation.

First, I will rename `mtcars` to `mtcars2` because `mtcars` is a stored data set and I don't want both to override it and because `setDT` actually can't override stored data sets, so lets say that in real life your data is called `mtcars2`

```
library(data.table)
mtcars2 <- copy(mtcars)
```

Next, we will convert to `data.table` objects, while keeping row names, and setting a key for a faster join

```
setkey(setDT(mtcars2, keep.rownames = TRUE), rn)
setkey(setDT(mtcars11, keep.rownames = TRUE), rn)
```

Now we will perform an *inner join* over `rn` (the key) while keeping original column names using `suffixes = NULL`

```
Res <- merge(mtcars2, mtcars11, suffixes = NULL)
```

Now we can `melt` by `rn` and then `dcast` by unique columns while computing the mean

```
dcast(melt(Res, "rn"), rn ~ variable, mean.default)
#                      rn  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#  1:         AMC Javelin 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#  2:  Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#  3:          Camaro Z28 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#  4:   Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#  5:          Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#  6:    Dodge Challenger 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#  7:          Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#  8:        Ferrari Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#  9:            Fiat 128 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# 10:         Honda Civic 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# 11:      Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 12:   Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 13: Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
# 14:        Lotus Europa 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
# 15:           Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 16:            Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# 17:           Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# 18:            Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
# 19:           Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
# 20:          Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
# 21:         Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
# 22:       Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# 23:      Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# 24:       Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# 25:             Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```